# Twilio) java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, tomcat, jwt, twilio, apache-tomee

I am trying to use the Twilio SMS API. It works fine when I use the API in a separate file, but when I add it in my project, but it shows `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE`. I don't know what to do. Please help me out.

Below there are jar files I am using.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:620)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:156)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:123)
    at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.<init>(NetworkHttpClient.java:63)
    at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.<init>(NetworkHttpClient.java:35)
    at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient$Builder.build(TwilioRestClient.java:116)
    at com.twilio.Twilio.buildRestClient(Twilio.java:187)
    at com.twilio.Twilio.getRestClient(Twilio.java:163)
    at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:40)
    at filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at filter.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Twilio API code is below:

```
import com.twilio.Twilio; 
import com.twilio.converter.Promoter; 
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message; 
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber; 

import java.net.URI; 
import java.math.BigDecimal; 

public class Example { 
    // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/console 
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "[AccountSid]"; 
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "[AuthToken]"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN); 
        Message message = Message.creator( 
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("+61000000000"),   
                "Your message")      
            .create(); 

        System.out.println(message.getSid()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to include and use the Twilio library?

Comment: well.. it's a very big project and that file has over 500 lines... but I use the code above.

Comment: If you include the file as written above in your project, do you get the error?

Comment: Seems like there are different versions of same jar file which causes conflict

Comment: yes, I got the error if I include the code in the project.

Comment: Yeah I think so. so I deleted the same jar files with different version, but still shows java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE error.

Comment: @SamrajEdwinSamuel most likely is right. I hope you have library version management, like **maven**'s dependencies specification for transitive dependencies and such.

Comment: well.. I don't have maven...